# for loop displaying every 3rd number

Tags: c#, for-loop

I want to create a for loop in a C# windows form app that displays every 3rd number in a label.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] array = new int[100];
            for (int i = 10; i < 101; i += 3)               
            label1.Text = i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to produce the output in a console app:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 10; i < 101; i += 3)

            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using two loops ?

Comment: The double loop is wrong, but also, you will keep overwriting the label text. Put label1.Text += " " + i.ToString(); inside the first loop and get rid of the second.

Comment: I didn't comment out the foreach loop. That was a mistake.

Comment: see sharper, thank you. your feedback helped, it actually solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use operator `+=` instead of `=` to append all strings together.  And add a `linefeed` separator.

```
label1.Text += i.ToString() + "\n";
```

Comment: The operator and separator were my issues (besides not deleting the array). Thank you, Jocelyn

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is very strange. You are iterating from `10 ... 100` incrementing the counter by `3` then you are iterating every element in the `int[]` (which is just full of zero's). Now your console app is doing the first loop and outputting all the results `i`.

Now the reason this isnt working is you are setting the `Text` property to the current value of `i` so my guess is you are only getting the last number (100).

This is an easy fix.

```
string output = "";
for (int i = 10; i < 101; i += 3)
{
    output += i.ToString() + " ";
}
label1.Text = output;
```

This creates a string that starts at `10` and outputs every third number until the loop is finished.

Answer (score 0):

It is much the same as in the console application. Only diference is you have to concatenate the next number to the displayed string.

A very simple solution (assuming you have a single line `TextBox`)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     for (int i = 10; i < 101; i += 3)
     {
        label1.Text = label1.Text + i.ToString();
     }
}
```

If you have many manipulations on a `string`, you should consider using a `stringbuilder`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var sb = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 10; i < 101; i += 3)
     {
        sb.Append(i);
     }
     label1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```